# Problem with azure blob storage encoding when uploading a file

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm uploading files to Azure Blob Storage with the .Net package specifying the encoding iso-8859-1. The stream seems ok in Memory but when I upload to the blob storage it ends with corrupted characters that seems that could not be converted to that encoding. It would seem as if the file gets storaged in a corrupted state and when I download it again and check it the characters get all messed up. Here is the code I'm using.

```
    public static async Task<bool> UploadFileFromStream(this CloudStorageAccount account, string containerName, string destBlobPath, string fileName, Stream stream, Encoding encoding)
    {
        if (account is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(account));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(containerName)) throw new ArgumentException("message", nameof(containerName));
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(destBlobPath)) throw new ArgumentException("message", nameof(destBlobPath));
        if (stream is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(stream));
        stream.Position = 0;
        CloudBlockBlob blob = GetBlob(account, containerName, $"{destBlobPath}/{fileName}");
        blob.Properties.ContentType = FileUtils.GetFileContentType(fileName);
        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream, encoding);
        var ct = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        await blob.UploadTextAsync(ct, encoding ?? Encoding.UTF8, AccessCondition.GenerateEmptyCondition(), new BlobRequestOptions(), new OperationContext());
        return true;
    }
```

This is the file just before uploading it

```
<provinciaDatosInmueble>Sevilla</provinciaDatosInmueble>
<inePoblacionDatosInmueble>969</inePoblacionDatosInmueble>
<poblacionDatosInmueble>Valencina de la Concepción</poblacionDatosInmueble>
```

and this is the file after the upload

```
<provinciaDatosInmueble>Sevilla</provinciaDatosInmueble>
<inePoblacionDatosInmueble>969</inePoblacionDatosInmueble>
<poblacionDatosInmueble>Valencina de la Concepci�n</poblacionDatosInmueble>
```

The encoding I send is ISO-5589-1 in the parameter of the encoding. Anybody knows why Blob Storage seems to ignore the encoding I'm specifying? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI - [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @DavidMakogon edited, but I don't think it was any code/data/error relevant for the technical point in this question, those are just names, text plain.

Comment: It's relevant for anyone who wants to copy/paste your data, use a screen reader, etc. Not everyone can read (or use) an image of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could able to achieve this using [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/12.12.0-beta.1) instead of [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage?msclkid=3e01f243c5cb11ec838c5ea92eb28a81) which is a legacy Storage SDK. Below is the code that worked for us.

```
class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            string sourceContainerName = "<Source_Container_Name>";
            string destBlobPath = "<Destination_Path>";
            string fileName = "<Source_File_name>";

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient("<Your_Connection_String>");
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(sourceContainerName);
            BlobClient blobClientSource = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
            BlobClient blobClientDestination = containerClient.GetBlobClient(destBlobPath);

            // Reading From Blob
            var line =" ";
            if (await blobClientSource.ExistsAsync())
            {
                var response = await blobClientSource.DownloadAsync();

                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.Value.Content))
                {
                    line = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
                }
            }
            
            // Writing To Blob
            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(content))
                blobClientDestination.Upload(ms);
        }
    }
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

Comment: FYI my comment to the OP is just as relevant here: Please edit to include properly-formatted text, not an image of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Aside from that, please edit your question to explain why/how your answer differs from what the OP originally did.

Comment: @DavidMakogon The picture I have uploaded is just to show how it appears in a storage account and to show that it is working.